# Maui android local secure web service: Certificate path not found

Tags: c#, android, certificate, httpclient, maui

I'm having this exception: "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I tried to follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check

Added this to my code:

```
    private static HttpClient Client;
    private ReservationModel[] Reservations;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        HttpClientHandler insecureHandler = GetInsecureHandler();
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(insecureHandler);

        var response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://10.0.2.2:7284/reservations",
        "{}");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        Reservations = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReservationModel[]>();
        }       
    }

    public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
        {
            if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                return true;
            return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
        };
        return handler;
    }
```

But still getting the same exception, I wonder if it is possible to make this approach work, without having the need to Enable HTTP clear-text traffic?

**Updated**

Exception (sorry for using image but was not able to place text):
[image]

Regards

Comment: is your custom handler being called?  Is it returning `true` on local requests?

Comment: No it is not getting called, and I don't understand why, I will but the entire exception on my question

Comment: I wonder if not being called is related to this comment above the method in that link: `// This method must be in a class in a platform project, even if the HttpClient object is constructed in a shared project.` I'm vague on exactly how Maui binds to each platform. (If it was Xamarin, it would belong in the .Android project, but for Maui, there is only one project.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve MAUI as a folder Platforms  that contains each of the platforms. I already created a class and putted it inside the Android platform folder but the handler is still not being called... I guess it is because it is being triggered a different exception.